# Oauth2 client logout doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I try to use the approach, described here https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout :

**So I have following backend codebase:**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Controller
public class ClientApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientApplication.class);

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String home(Principal user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws ServletException {
        model.addAttribute("name", user.getName());
        return "hello";
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ClientApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name=application").run(args);
    }
}
```

**and following frontend:**

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT'
                    || settings.type == 'DELETE') {
                    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/
                            .test(settings.url))) {
                        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN",
                            Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        var logout = function () {
            $.post("/client/logout", function () {
                $("#user").html('');
                $(".unauthenticated").show();
                $(".authenticated").hide();
            });
            return true;
        };
        $(function() {
            $("#logoutButton").on("click", function () {
                logout();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and html:

```
<input type="button" id="logoutButton" value="Logout"/>
```

But it doesn't work. Behaviour the following:

After successfull login in application I click to the logout button
It fires the POST`http://localhost:9999/client/logout`
`http://localhost:9999/client/logout` redirects to the `http://localhost:9999/client` but this page doesn't exist. It then I access `localhost:8080/client/hello` - I see secured page

### P.S.

`/client` is application context:

`application.yml` fragment:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /client
```

**source code on gitub:**
client - https://github.com/gredwhite/logour_social-auth-client (use `localhost:9999/client/hello` url)
server - https://github.com/gredwhite/logout_social-auth-server

Answer (score 0):

The logout endpoint should be `/logout` instead of `/client/logout`.

Comment: **/client**  is application context

Comment: In the question, you use both absolute and relative URLs that do not match. It was therefore not quite clear whether these are correct. `/hello` is not valid in case `/client` is application context.

Comment: I'm not yet allowed to comment on your question, so I put my comment here...If you change `.logoutSuccessUrl("/")` to `.logoutSuccessUrl("/hello")` you should get to the correct page directly

Comment: unfortunalely it is not the truth

Comment: I tried your advice. If you have time to find out - I can shre github repo with my example.